# How do I know if a scheduled Lambda was not executed?

Tags: amazon-web-services, lambda, aws-lambda

I have a scheduled Lambda which MUST run on a scheduled time every day.

I want to make an alarm if it was not ran for some reason.

Is this achievable?

EDIT:
I would like to achieve that using the CDK, please point to the documentation url (even if its not cdk) in your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although unlikely that cloudwatch event will misfire, you can use invocations metric and create a Cloudwatch alarm based on that.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-lambda.Function.html#metricwbrinvocationsprops